# How can I update DOM while a method is running?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing a simple tool that works on the client side. Basically, the user brings in a file, presses a button to start it, it does stuff with it (takes about 10-15 seconds), and then it gives the modified file back.

Unfortunately, as soon as they press the button to start the method, the DOM doesn't update until the method is finished, so there's no feedback until it's all finished, which is quite frustrating.

In the template section, I have:

`<p v-if="processingStatus==1">Processing data...</p>`

The "processingStatus" variable is set to 0 by default.

In the method, which is "processData" and is called when the button is pressed, it starts with

```
this.processingStatus = 1
```

And then proceeds to process the data.

Unfortunately, the "Processing data..." tag doesn't show up until the method is finished. How can I force VueJS to render the DOM while the method is running?

Comment: what does `processData` do?

Comment: It goes through a huge array, searches for elements in that array in another array, and if it finds them it deletes them. It's all client side.

Comment: My guess is you are changing the value of `processingStatus` inside `if` which has a different scope. It works fine for me if I create a variable for `this` inside the function but outside any if statements. For your reference https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/j0u14675/

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't running inside of a setTimeout function. Doing that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are saying that `processData` is doing (going through a bunch of data in arrays), my guess is that it is not running async and is locking the javascript thread until it is done.

What you need to do is inside `processData` is set the is processing variable like you are, but then do all the actual work inside a promise or some other mechanism to release control and update the UI.

Potentially you could also call

`vm.$forceUpdate();`

before starting all your array work.